# How to use AsEnumerable without System.Data

Tags: c#, linq

I have a project that, due to namespace conflicts, I don't want to include System.Data with "using" at the top of my cs file.

However, I want to use a LINQ statement that uses .AsEnumerable(), which is located in System.Data.

Is there a way to write my LINQ statement such that .AsEnumerable() knows it comes from System.Data?

Something like...

```
var x = myTable.System.Data.AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Did you know that you can use [alias](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765(v=vs.71).aspx) around a using statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
someDataTable.AsEnumerable()
```

becomes

```
System.Data.DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(someDataTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import static members from `DataTableExtensions` class (and extension methods are static)

```
using static System.Data.DataTableExtensions;
```

after that `.AsEnumerable()` extension will be available:

```
myTable.AsEnumerable()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the DataRows without the extension, and avoid the `.AsEnumerable` overhead:

```
var rows = dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>();
```

[That is what `.AsEnumerable` uses, but it also does some extra stuff that are not needed in most cases](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/EnumerableRowCollection.cs,068ee8343125ebde)